# Excel worksheet screen not updating even after Screenupdating set to True

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an unusual issue with Excel worksheet being unresponsive to keyboard arrow moves, Excel closure button being unresponsive, etc. I have VBA code lines and I have triple-checked that `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of those code lines. For now, the only thing that helps "unfreeze" the worksheet is to MANUALLY run a simple procedure with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. As an extra layer of verification, I have opened another file with a simpler VBA code line and 100% operational, and now I see exactly the same issue. 
My only suspicion is that it has something to do with Excel itself rather than the code. Is there anyone having the same issue?

UPDATE: So as to provide evidence that this is not code related, I have re-checked this file on a different machine and everything works just fine. I am now sure of this issue being related to my PC or Excel itself...

Comment: Use `DoEvents` inside your `For` and `Do While` Loops

Comment: Many things can cause your code to "skip" a line. If...Then statements, For...Next w/ Exit For, etc. It's difficult to diagnose a problem with limited information. Other issues could be your error handling methods. I would recommend you use your own error handling as opposed to using something like `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Which version of Office are you using ? Check your video display driver. Sometimes Microsoft offers a better driver than the manufacturer. Just a thought.

Comment: There's not enough context in thsi question to reliably answer it without making assumptions. Please [edit] to include the relevant code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Should I delete the answer I posted, since it is speculation of what OP wanted?

Comment: @Moacir nah, you might have guessed right =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug and everyone else in this thread, thank you all for your replies! I could post the code but it's too lengthy and there are multiple procedures and userforms all interconnected, so it wouldn't even be feasible to do that. 

Please look at the UPDATE I posted to my initial question, since I noticed all works fine on another machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DoEvents` on your code to "regain" control of Excel. 
For example in the code

```
For i = 1 to 99999999999
 'humongous code here
Next i
```

It would maybe cause the excel to freeze. To circunvent this, do:

```
For i = 1 to 99999999999
DoEvents
 'humongous code here
Next i
```

This way it will always unlock excel before the code being executed.

Be careful, as this lets you edit fields and this would interrupt the execution of the code, causing unwanted effects.

Just for example, I usually do the following:

```
timesincelastcheck = Now
For i = 1 to 99999999999
If Now - timesincelastcheck >= TimeValue("0:00:04") Then
    DoEvents
    timesincelastcheck = Now
End If
 'humongous code here
Next i
```

So it will only do the unlock if 4 seconds has passed since the last unlock.

Comment: thank you for a post but this is not an answer to the question. As I mentioned in my question, my issue is not code-related, since the file, which used to work fine, doesn't seem to update my screen anymore.